# Is there a Quick Look plugin for epub?

Tags: epub, quicklook-plugin

Is there a Quick Look plugin to preview [.epub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EPUB) (ebook) files?

Comment: @LаngLаngС It's **Quick Look** not QuickLook. See: https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/mh14119/mac

Comment: @user3439894 Oh. Which one is canonical `$ /Library/QuickLook` or https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quicklook ? Honestly confused. Was that changed at some time?

Comment: @LаngLаngС What something is called and how it might be stored on disk are two entirely different things! **Apple** clearly refers to it as **Quick Look** and to OP originally had it that way until lejonet changed it and grg corrected it, which is what I did after it was once again wrongfully edited.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, there are several:

- [ePub-quicklook](https://github.com/jaketmp/ePub-quicklook) @ github (free)
- [eBookQuickLook](https://web.archive.org/web/20111228223702/http://lymes.altervista.org/blog/?p=378) (free) (outdated)
- [EPUB QuickLook plugin](http://people.ict.usc.edu/~leuski/programming/epub-quickview.php) (free)

Comment: A quick note on the differences would have been nice.

Comment: None of these appear to be working in current macOS, as of 2023.

Answer (score 6):

[EPUB-Plugins](https://github.com/GenjiApp/EPUB-Plugins) Quick Look & Spotlight plugins. OT [QLMobi](https://github.com/bfabiszewski/QLMobi).

Comment: This one worked for me (Mojave 10.14.2).  Went to [Releases page](https://github.com/GenjiApp/EPUB-Plugins/releases), downloaded `EPUB.qlgenerator_v1.1.1.zip`, unzipped, dragged `EPUB.qlgenerator` into `~/Library/QuickLook`, did a `qlmanage -r` and voila, we're in business.  Finally!  (NB I'm not interested in the Spotlight indexing part.)

BTW this one previews not just the cover/metadata but the contents.

BTW^2 I'm using [QLMobi](https://github.com/bfabiszewski/QLMobi) for other ebook formats (prc, mobi, azw, azw3, azw4 and some pdb), for those looking.

Comment: Works for me in Ventura. But it's not signed, so you may need to remove the quarantine attribute: xattr -r -d com.apple.quarantine /path/to/EPUB.qlgenerator

Answer (score 2):

[ePub-quicklook](https://github.com/jaketmp/ePub-quicklook/) was maintained up to 2016, but says it does not work in Mojave or later.

It comes in two parts:

The `epub.qlgenerator` plugin is designed to extract the cover images from EPUB files to use as the file icon, and present a nice overview of the EPUB in QuickLook.

The `epub.mdimporter` plugin is designed to extract information from EPUB files (metadata as well as text content) and index it so that Spotlight can search it.

To install, download the either files, or both from [github Releases](https://github.com/jaketmp/ePub-quicklook/releases/tag/v1.8).

Then copy the unzipped `epub.qlgenerator` file into `/Library/QuickLook/` (for all users) or `~/Library/QuickLook/` (for the current user only).

And copy the unzipped `epub.mdimporter` file into `/Library/Spotlight/` (for all cusers) or `~/Library/Spotlight/` (for the current user only).